# How to make a shake animation adding feature on openlayers 3

Tags: openlayers, features, animation

Have you an idea of animate function to shake a feature when it's added to the map ?

I've found only this animation from openlayers 3 samples: 
[Animate feature example openlayers 3](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.1/examples/feature-animation.html?q=animation)

Answer (score 1):

I think it should suffice to animate the feature yourself. I will try to demonstrate below together with some pseudo-code, since I haven't played around with vector layers on OL3 yet.

Since you have the addFeature event, you can make use of that:

```
source.on('addfeature', function(e) {
  animateStart(e.feature);
});
```

Then you can perform a simple animation along the lines of:

```
var frameCount = 0;
var timeOutHandle = null;
var initialGeometry = null;

function animateStart(_oFeature) {
    initialGeometry = _oFeature.Geometry;    //assuming this exists
    timeOutHandle = window.setInterval(function (feature) {
        if (frameCount==5) {   //assume 5 frames
            window.clearTimeout(timeOutHandle);
            feature.Geometry = initialGeometry;
            frameCount = 0;
            return;
        }
        else {
            //you need the resolution for the animation to be meaningful for any zoom level
            var resolution = map.getView().getResolution();
            if (frameCount % 2 == 0) {
                //move each point in geometry to the west - assume pseudo-code here
                for (var pt in feature.Geometry.Points) {
                    pt[0] -= resolution * 8;    //this 8 can be something that you try and choose
                }
                //maybe refresh/redraw layer?
            }
            else {
                //move each point in geometry to the east - assume pseudo-code here
                for (var pt in feature.Geometry.Points) {
                    pt[0] += resolution * 8;
                }
                //maybe refresh/redraw layer?
            }
            frameCount++;
        }
    } (_oFeature), 100);
}
```

Again I should emphasize that this is pretty much pseudo-code, but it should point you in the right direction.